# !str_detect(col, pattern) removes more rows from data.frame than are found with str_detect(col, pattern)

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a large data.frame / tibble with several character columns and am in the process of cleaning data there. One column contains city names. Sometimes a row does not contain a city name (i.e. City is "" or City may also be NA). Sometimes cities are marked with a degree symbol (i.e. "°" or '\u00B0').

Example situation using tidyverse / dplyr and stringr:

```
nrow(df) #5000
df.degree <- df %>% filter(str_detect(city, '\u00B0')) 
nrow(df.degree) #30
df.withoutdegree <- df %>% filter(!str_detect(city, '\u00B0'))
nrow(df.withoutdegree) #4500
```

My goal is to remove only the 30 rows that contain the degree symbol in the city column. If I look for those rows, I get them using filter and str_detect. Negating str_detect removes many more rows than just those 30 though.

This seems to be a case where I missed some obvious documentation or parameter I need to set or different approach I'm missing. However, I can't seem to find it. Can you point me into the right direction?

Any hints with code examples on making this even more elegant (maybe with "contains()"?) are also very much appreciated.

Thanks! :)

PS: The following works just fine btw:

```
df.withoutdegree <- df %>% filter(!(grepl('\u00B0', city, ignore.case = TRUE)))
nrow(df.withoutdegree) #4970
```

However, I find the code harder to read for peers and I'm generally interested to learn about why negating str_detect doesn't work in this case.

Comment: can you try running `str_which()` to identify some cases that it is excluding which should not be excluded as per your logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

City contains `NA` values so make sure that you don't filter them out

```
df <- df %>% filter( is.na(city) | !str_detect(city, '\u00B0'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to remove values `\u00B0` then this should work:

```
df <- df %>% filter(!str_detect(city, '\\\u00B0'))
```

Comment: I thought so, too, however, interestingly I will receive a df containing 4500 rows instead of 4970 for my example case where I have 5000 rows to start with and 30 rows containing the degree symbol.

Comment: Sorry just saw the total number of rows. Can you post the output of `table(df$city)` please?

Comment: The original data is confidential :( I'll try to come up with a sample df this evening.

Comment: \ is a meta character. Have just replaced it with \\\. Does it work now?

Comment: No, unfortunately, it doesn't :(

Comment: I am seeing this as a bug, too. I have 3 patterns that I want removed from my dataset.Using a single one removes more rows than it should, and using all 3 removes all my rows. This works without a problem with `!grepl`. I have used `!str_detect` and `str_detect(negate = TRUE)` with no success.